# How to consolidate only select values in a dictionary with repeated keys

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have a list of dictionaries that contain entries that have the same key for 'name'. I want to merge all dictionaries with duplicate keys while retaining their name value but summing up their weights.

The code below will output:

> {'name': ('jake', 'sully', 'jake', 'sully'), 'weight': 2.0}

```
# Initialising list of dictionary
ini_dict = [{'name': ('jake', 'sully'), 'weight': 1.0}, {'name': ('jake', 'sully'), 'weight': 1.0}]
# printing initial dictionary
print("initial dictionary", str(ini_dict))

# sum the values with same keys
counter = collections.Counter()
for d in ini_dict:
    counter.update(d)

result = dict(counter)
print(result)
```

However that is smashing together the names as well when in reality I am going for:

```
{'name': ('jake', 'sully), 'weight': 2.0}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal dict:

```
result = {}
for d in ini_dict:
    result[d["name"]] = result.get(d["name"], 0) + d["weight"]
```

The result will be a dict with `name` as keys and `weight` as values:

```
{('jake', 'sully'): 2.0}
```

If you wanted it back in list form:

```
lst = [{"name":k, "weight":v} for k, v in result.items()]
```

The names in the tuple must be in the same order. `('jake', 'sully') != ('sully', 'jake')`.

Comment: can you explain what this line is doing? 

`esult[d["name"]] = result.get(d["name"], 0) + d["weight"]`

also, what is the 0 parameter? thanks

Comment: the `get` method of `dict` returns the value of the key, if the key is found, otherwise returns the default value `0`.  I used it, because i needed a starting value to sum the weight.

Comment: So in the first step, when the key is not yet in the dict, it will be `result[('jake','sully')] = 0 + 1.0`. In the second step: `result[('jake','sully')] = 1.0 + 1.0`